# How to print multi-digit numbers like a 7-segment display

Tags: java

I am just wondering whether is it possible to display number in digital format.
In this we are accepting number from console.

For example:

```
123 should be display in following format, and in one line.
  _  _
| _| _|
| |_ _|
```

I tried using switch case but not got appropriate method

```
"arg" is char array;
char c;
for(i=0;i<3;i++)
{
c=arg[i];
switch(char)
{

    case '1' : System.out.println("|");
               System.out.println("|");
               break;
    case '2' : System.out.println("-");
               System.out.println(" "+"|");
               System.out.println("-");
               System.out.println("|");
               System.out.println("-");
               break;

  same for all digit
}
}
```

I know this is not a correct solution to display.

Is it any alternative for this using java.

**EDIT**
Updated code which is suggested by Joe. It works.

```
        /**
        * @author Amit
        */
        public class DigitalDisplay {
            /**
             * @param args
             */
                public static void main(String[] args) {
        String [][] num=new String[4][3];
        num[0][0]="|-|";
        num[0][1]="| |";
        num[0][2]="|_|";

        num[1][0]=" |";
        num[1][1]=" |";
        num[1][2]=" |";

        num[2][0]=" -|";
        num[2][1]=" _|";
        num[2][2]=" |_";

        num[3][0]=" -|";
        num[3][1]=" _|";
        num[3][2]=" _|";
        int[] input = {2,1,3}; 
        for (int line = 0; line < 3; line++)
        {          
            for (int inputI=0; inputI < input.length; inputI++)
            {
                int value = input[inputI];
                System.out.print(num[value][line]);
                System.out.print("  ");
            }          
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

**OUTPUT**

 -|   |   -|  
 _|   |   _|  
 |_   |   _|
```

@Joe: Thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with your solution? use "_" instead of "-" and it should work

Comment: "Not got appropriate method" - be more descriptive.  What is the problem?

Comment: I think you need to take a step back - where are you wanting to display these numbers (what is the context), and why in this particular form? Could your requirements be met by using a different Font?

Comment: @Hachi: I used same _ thing. but dont know whether is it optimal solution.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: In this I am displaying each number on next line. Is it possible to display in same line? Is there any alternative better approach to display it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have more than one character, you need to scan across each line, building it up.

All of the following is pseudocode, but I am sure you can translate it into Java. You will need to create a grid and ensure that each digit has the same width and height.

1 - Set up your initial data for each number. You could do this as a 2d array (dimension 1: digit, dimension 2: line) For example:

```
numbers[0][0] = "|-|"
numbers[0][1] = "| |"
numbers[0][2] = "|_|"

numbers[1][0] = "  |"
numbers[1][1] = "  |"
numbers[1][2] = "  |"
```

2 - For each line that makes up the character, scan across each digit in your input and write the appropriate string. This will build up the characters line by line.

```
input = [1,2,3]
digit_height = 3

for line digit_height:
   for digit in input:
       print numbers[digit][line]
       print "  " to space between characters
   print new line
```

Fine, here's the java:

```
    int[] input = {2,1,3}; 
    for (int line = 0; line < 3; line++)
    {          
        for (int inputI=0; inputI < input.length; inputI++)
        {
            int value = input[inputI];
            System.out.print(num[value][line]);
            System.out.print("  ");
        }          
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: @Joe: Thanks for some good solution but still it prints on next line. Is it possible to display on same line?

Comment: It shouldn't. Did you code this up? Show your code and I'll have a look.

Comment: @Joe: I have added code as you suggested. Please let me know where should I modify so that it will print on same line.

Comment: You wrote `println` not `print`. This will insert a new line character and you do not want that. You should also put a `println` after the `j` loop.

Comment: @joe:To print only single number we need to print on next line so that it will display complete number. If I put print instead of println then for "1" number it will print like "||" same line.To display second number we need to position cursor such that it will number after first number.

Comment: @Joe: Thanks it works. You are great..will update whole code as you mention.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example on digital clock, it may helpfull to you [Digital clock](http://www.muquit.com/muquit/software/jdgclock/jdgclock.html)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method would be, draw an 8, and store it. Then on the basis of the required number, you would know which stroke of 8 has to be printed, and which doesn't need to be printed.

Example:

8:

```
 _
|_|
|_|
```

For 1, just print the right half,

```
|
|
```

For 2, ignore the corresponding strokes,

```
  _
  _|
 |_
```

Similarly for others. This is how a 7 segment display actually works as well.

Have an array store the values of the 7 strokes needed.
Then for 8, your array could be something like : `{1,1,1,1,1,1,1}`
For 1, your array could be like : `{0,0,0,1,0,0,1}` where 0 means not to print the stroke, and 1 means to print the stroke.

Then on the basis of this array, print the strokes. It is better than simply having a `switch` case and printing the corresponding for every number. Just loop through the array elements, deciding whether or not to print the stroke.

For the example you have given,123,the have a 2D array. The values can go `{{0,0,0,1,0,0,1},{1,0,1,1,1,1,0},{1,0,1,1,0,1,1}}`

Then compare the values from the array and print your strokes!

EDIT:
sample code:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s;
s = br.readLine();
int n;
n = Integer.parseInt(s);
int stroke = 1;
int arr[] = new int[8];
if(s == 2)
    arr[] = {1,0,1,1,1,1,0};
for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{
if(arr[i] == 1 && stroke = 1)
   System.out.println(" _");
   stroke++;
   break;
if(arr[i] == 1 && stroke = 2)
   System.out.print("|");
   stroke++;
   break;
if(arr[i] == 1 && stroke = 3)
   System.out.print("_");
   stroke++;
   break;
if(arr[i] == 1 && stroke = 4)
   System.out.println("|");
   stroke++;
   break;
if(arr[i] == 1 && stroke = 5)
   System.out.print("|");
   stroke++;
   break;
if(arr[i] == 1 && stroke = 6)
   System.out.println("_");
   stroke++;
   break;
if(arr[i] == 1 && stroke = 7)
   System.out.println("|");
   stroke++;
   break;
}
```

Once one number is printed, you can use the [JLine](http://jline.sourceforge.net/) library to replace your cursor on your console to start over with the next number.(Though I'm not sure about it).

It might require a little bit more tweaking to be exactly the answer required!

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about how to actually do it.

Comment: @KazekageGaara: can you please provide more details about this?

Comment: @KazekageGaara this doesn't specify how to print multiple characters in one line.

Comment: @KazekageGaara: What is used of stroke in this? I think if we only used if(arr[i] == 1) condition then also it works. Is it possible to display on single line without using JLine library?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 different, very basic syntax errors here, not to mention any logical errors.

- `char` is a reserved word, so you cannot use it for a variable name.
- `switch` is written lowercased (like all other keywords in Java)
- `"1"` is a string literal, not a `char` literal. Use single quotes for `char` literals.

Comment: Thanks for correction in syntax errors. I will update it. I just wanted know any other alternative better logic for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new class with the output of the numbers plus a function to store what you want to print and a function to print.

Example:

```
public class DigitalNumbers{

   private String buffer = "";
   private int lines = 5; // Number's height
   private String number0[] = {
      "___ ",
      "|  | ",
      "|  | ",
      "|  | ",
      "¯¯¯ "
   };
   private String number1[] = {
      "  ",
      "| ",
      "| ",
      "| ",
      "  "
   };
   //... 

   public DigitalNumbers(){

   }

   public void add(char c){
      buffer += c;
   }

   public void print(){
      for(int i=0; i<lines; i++){
         for(int j=0; j<buffer.length(); j++){
            switch(buffer.charAt(j)){
               case '0': System.out.print(number0[i]); break;
               case '1': System.out.print(number1[i]); break;
               //...
               default: break;
            }
         }
         System.out.print("\n");         
      }
      buffer = "";
   }

}
```

And then use like this:

```
DigitalNumbers DG = new DigitalNumbers();
for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
   DN.add(arg[i]);
}
DG.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //this program help you 

import java.util.*;
public class Test{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
           Scanner inr = new Scanner(System.in);
            char c = inr.next().charAt(0); 
           // Add the necessary code in the below space 


  if(c=='2'||c=='3'||c=='5'||c=='6'||c=='7'||c=='8'||c=='9'||c=='0')
   System.out.println(" _ ");
  else
   System.out.println("   ");

  if(c=='4'||c=='5'||c=='6'||c=='8'||c=='9'||c=='0')
   System.out.print("|");
  else
   System.out.print(" ");

  if(c=='2'||c=='3'||c=='4'||c=='5'||c=='6'||c=='8'||c=='9')
   System.out.print("_");
  else
   System.out.print(" ");

  if(c=='1'||c=='2'||c=='3'||c=='4'||c=='7'||c=='0'||c=='8'||c=='9')
    System.out.println("|");
   else
    System.out.println(" ");



  if(c=='6'||c=='2'||c=='8'||c=='0')
   System.out.print("|");
  else
   System.out.print(" ");
  if(c=='2'||c=='3'||c=='5'||c=='6'||c=='8'||c=='9'||c=='0')
   System.out.print("_");
  else
   System.out.print(" ");

  if(c=='1'||c=='3'||c=='4'||c=='5'||c=='6'||c=='7'||c=='8'||c=='9'||c=='0')
   System.out.println("|");
  else
   System.out.println(" ");
   }
}
```

Comment: i know this is old question. but solution is new man, I am very thankful for your welcome.