# Need a program to convert number entered by the user (using BufferedReader) into a digital format

Tags: java

Here is what I have uptil now. I cant figure out how to do it for a number greater than 9.
Can you perhaps store multiple lines in a String??

```
import java.io.*;

class sample1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter a number b/w one and nine");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();

        if (a < 10) {
            switch (a) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println(" _ _");
                    System.out.println("|   |");
                    System.out.println("|   |");
                    System.out.println("|   |");
                    System.out.println("|_ _|");
                    break;

                case 1:
                    System.out.println("|");
                    System.out.println("|");
                    System.out.println("|");
                    System.out.println("|");
                    System.out.println("|");
                    break;


                case 2:
                    System.out.println(" _ _");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println(" _ _|");
                    System.out.println("|   ");
                    System.out.println("|_ _");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println(" _ _");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println(" _ _|");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println(" _ _|");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println("|");
                    System.out.println("|   ");
                    System.out.println("|_ _|");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    break;

                case 5:
                    System.out.println(" _ _");
                    System.out.println("|");
                    System.out.println("|_ _");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println(" _ _|");
                    break;

                case 6:
                    System.out.println(" _ _");
                    System.out.println("|");
                    System.out.println("|_ _");
                    System.out.println("|   |");
                    System.out.println("|_ _|");
                    break;

                case 7:
                    System.out.println(" _ _");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    break;

                case 8:
                    System.out.println(" _ _");
                    System.out.println("|   |");
                    System.out.println("|_ _|");
                    System.out.println("|   |");
                    System.out.println("|_ _|");
                    break;

                case 9:
                    System.out.println(" _ _");
                    System.out.println("|   |");
                    System.out.println("|_ _|");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println(" _ _|");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when a number is divided by `10`?

Comment: You may have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686233/how-to-print-multi-digit-numbers-like-a-7-segment-display

Comment: Well this sounds very much like homework to me. Try to break it down in smaller sub-problems: first split the number into digits (as Boris suggested). Then, instead of displaying the lines directly, how about using StringBuilders to hold the output until you have the whole number processed?  So instead of System.out.println("|_ _|"); you could append this to a buffer.

Comment: woah guys im in 9th grade....... i know only the basics

Comment: what are StringBuilders??

Comment: If you promise me you will study a lot, I will write the solution and explain it to you, do we have a deal?

Comment: You should probably look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26231956/2413303

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can store multiple lines in a String by using the line separator variable.

```
String seperator = System.getproperty("line.seperator");
String lines = "line1"+seperator+"line2"+seperator+"line3"; // etc.
```

But to print all of an integers digits, you could do the following with a bit of simple string manipulation.

```
public static void printInt(int i){
    String str = i+"";
    for(char ch : str){
        int a = Integer.parseInt(ch+"");
        switch (a) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println(" _ _");
                    System.out.println("|   |");
                    System.out.println("|   |");
                    System.out.println("|   |");
                    System.out.println("|_ _|");
                    break;

                case 1:
                    System.out.println("|");
                    System.out.println("|");
                    System.out.println("|");
                    System.out.println("|");
                    System.out.println("|");
                    break;


                case 2:
                    System.out.println(" _ _");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println(" _ _|");
                    System.out.println("|   ");
                    System.out.println("|_ _");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println(" _ _");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println(" _ _|");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println(" _ _|");
                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println("|");
                    System.out.println("|   ");
                    System.out.println("|_ _|");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    break;

                case 5:
                    System.out.println(" _ _");
                    System.out.println("|");
                    System.out.println("|_ _");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println(" _ _|");
                    break;

                case 6:
                    System.out.println(" _ _");
                    System.out.println("|");
                    System.out.println("|_ _");
                    System.out.println("|   |");
                    System.out.println("|_ _|");
                    break;

                case 7:
                    System.out.println(" _ _");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    break;

                case 8:
                    System.out.println(" _ _");
                    System.out.println("|   |");
                    System.out.println("|_ _|");
                    System.out.println("|   |");
                    System.out.println("|_ _|");
                    break;

                case 9:
                    System.out.println(" _ _");
                    System.out.println("|   |");
                    System.out.println("|_ _|");
                    System.out.println("    |");
                    System.out.println(" _ _|");
                    break;
            }
    }
}
```

It works by converting the integer to a `String` and then looping through each character, converting it to an `int` each time.

Comment: With the program that you have edited it prints one number and the other number below it.

Comment: I need to print both the numbers side by side....... Even i figured that i could print them one below the other...

Comment: @AdityaGanti You didn't actually ask for them to be on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I did the solution cause I found it funny to do and never did anything like this before. So for the solution you just:

1. Reverse the number
2. Get the digits one by one from the number
3. Call a method that will print the respective number in the current line

The thing is that the console writes always in sequence, so you have to know beforehand what you are printing, before going to the next line.

Here is the code:

```
/**
* Created by rafael on 4/18/15.
*/
import java.io.*;

public class DigitalNumber {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter a number b/w one and nine");
        String input = br.readLine();
        int a = Integer.parseInt(new StringBuilder(input).reverse().toString());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println();


        int line = 0;
        while(line < 5) {
            int aux = a;
            while(aux > 0) {
                int digit = aux % 10;
                aux /= 10;
                printDigit(digit,line);
                System.out.print("    ");
            }
            ++line;
            System.out.println();
        }

    }

    public static void printDigit(int number, int line) {
        switch (number) {
            case 0:
                if(line == 0)
                    System.out.print(" _ _ ");
                if(line == 1)
                    System.out.print("|   |");
                if(line == 2)
                    System.out.print("|   |");
                if(line == 3)
                    System.out.print("|   |");
                if(line == 4)
                    System.out.print("|_ _|");
                break;

            case 1:
                if(line == 0)
                    System.out.print("|");
                if(line == 1)
                    System.out.print("|");
                if(line == 2)
                    System.out.print("|");
                if(line == 3)
                    System.out.print("|");
                if(line == 4)
                    System.out.print("|");
                break;


            case 2:
                if(line == 0)
                    System.out.print(" _ _ ");
                if(line == 1)
                    System.out.print("    |");
                if(line == 2)
                    System.out.print(" _ _|");
                if(line == 3)
                    System.out.print("|    ");
                if(line == 4)
                    System.out.print("|_ _ ");
                break;

            case 3:
                if(line == 0)
                    System.out.print(" _ _ ");
                if(line == 1)
                    System.out.print("    |");
                if(line == 2)
                    System.out.print(" _ _|");
                if(line == 3)
                    System.out.print("    |");
                if(line == 4)
                    System.out.print(" _ _|");
                break;

            case 4:
                if(line == 0)
                    System.out.print("|    ");
                if(line == 1)
                    System.out.print("|    ");
                if(line == 2)
                    System.out.print("|_ _|");
                if(line == 3)
                    System.out.print("    |");
                if(line == 4)
                    System.out.print("    |");
                break;

            case 5:
                if(line == 0)
                    System.out.print(" _ _ ");
                if(line == 1)
                    System.out.print("|    ");
                if(line == 2)
                    System.out.print("|_ _ ");
                if(line == 3)
                    System.out.print("    |");
                if(line == 4)
                    System.out.print(" _ _|");
                break;

            case 6:
                if(line == 0)
                    System.out.print(" _ _ ");
                if(line == 1)
                    System.out.print("|    ");
                if(line == 2)
                    System.out.print("|_ _ ");
                if(line == 3)
                    System.out.print("|   |");
                if(line == 4)
                    System.out.print("|_ _|");
                break;

            case 7:
                if(line == 0)
                    System.out.print(" _ _ ");
                if(line == 1)
                    System.out.print("    |");
                if(line == 2)
                    System.out.print("    |");
                if(line == 3)
                    System.out.print("    |");
                if(line == 4)
                    System.out.print("    |");
                break;

            case 8:
                if(line == 0)
                    System.out.print(" _ _ ");
                if(line == 1)
                    System.out.print("|   |");
                if(line == 2)
                    System.out.print("|_ _|");
                if(line == 3)
                    System.out.print("|   |");
                if(line == 4)
                    System.out.print("|_ _|");
                break;

            case 9:
                if(line == 0)
                    System.out.print(" _ _ ");
                if(line == 1)
                    System.out.print("|   |");
                if(line == 2)
                    System.out.print("|_ _|");
                if(line == 3)
                    System.out.print("    |");
                if(line == 4)
                    System.out.print(" _ _|");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't printing a certain line and checking for it in the method a little unnecessary? (compared to just printing all of the integer lines at once)

Comment: If you want print the numbers in the console next to each other you need to check the line.

Comment: Thank you a lot Rafael R. S. Robles ................... It does print them in the same line...

Comment: Just take the time to understand it, welcome.